# Alamofire multple URLS error handling at one place

Tags: swift, alamofire, rx-swift

I am using Alamofire my server will send errors like authentication failure which is common to most of the apis how can I handle this only at place.
Because the error needs to be handled same in all reponses.

Comment: Did you ever get any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to handle all these error as following:

```
func stautsHandler(_ response:HTTPURLResponse?, data:Data?, error:NSError?)
  {

    if  response?.statusCode == 400 {
      print("bad url")
    } else if response?.statusCode == 401 {
     print("unauthorized")
    } else if response?.statusCode == 403 {
      print("Forbidden")
    } else if response?.statusCode == 404  {
      print("file not found")
    }  else if response?.statusCode ==  500   {
      print("Problem connecting server: 500")
    }  else if response?.statusCode == -1005 {
     print("Lost Network Connectivity")
    } else if response?.statusCode == 408  {
      print("Connection Error: Please try again later")
    } else if error?.code == -1001  {
      print("Connection Error: Please try again later")
    } else if error?.code == -1009 {
      prrint("Connection Error: Please try again later")
    }
  }
```

You can pass the response, error, data from alamofire to this method. Call this method as following:

```
if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
    //HANDLE YOUR RESPONSE
} else {
        stautsHandler( response.response, data: response.data as Data?, error: response.result.error as NSError?)
}
```